# Error encountered while running react-native run-android: Execution failed for task ':app:installDebug'

Tags: react-native

I encountered the following error messages and I do not understand why I am unable to proceed with the run-android command even though I have an emulator on.
[image]

enter image description here

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: Pay attention to [```adb``` is not recignized as ... command](https://www.google.com.tr/search?q=react+native+android+adb+is+not+recognized+as&oq=react+native+android+adb+is+not+recognized+as&aqs=chrome..69i57.7446j0j7&sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8)

Comment: @milkersarac Ignore the adb install.. it's the ones above it that matters. I do not think that i have adb installed or something..

Comment: Without ```adb``` you could not send any install package to neither emulator or actual device. You can check [this](https://developer.android.com/studio/command-line/adb.html). You should think about having ```adb``` installed properly.

Comment: @milkersarac I followed the link [link](https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/getting-started.html) step by step and it gave me that error. I will try manually installing adb.

Comment: @milkersarac I've managed to find the directory my adb is installed in and I manually ran the `adb install app-debug.apk` at the directory. The auto installer when I do `react-native run-android` doesn't seem to work for the app-debug.apk part. It works now but I'm still disturbed by the fact that it is unable to automatically setup everything when i use `react-native run-android`. Do you have any idea why that is the case?

Comment: Sorry, it can be anything. However be sure that before running ```react-native run-android```, start your android emulator. I think you have Windows, I do not have any experience on that.

Comment: @milkersarac Alright I am able to get it to run successfully. Thanks for your help! :)